# how to bind params data to domain object that has a list/set property?

Tags: java, grails, data-binding, groovy, grails-2.0

I am puzzled by a behavior I'm facing with grails data binding. I will start with the controller code

```
def saveQuestion(){
   QuestionSurvey question = new QuestionSurvey();
   bindData(question, params);
   question.save(); 
}
```

Also the QuestionSurvey domain looks like

```
class QuestionSurvey {

    String questionText
    QuestionTypeSurvey questionType

    static hasMany = [options: QuestionOptionSurvey]

    static mapping = {  
        questionType enumType: 'ordinal'
    }

    static constraints = {}
}
```

Also, QuestionOptionSurvey domain looks like

```
class QuestionOptionSurvey {

    String optionText

    static belongsTo = [question: QuestionSurvey]

    static constraints = { }
}
```

The binding I think is working for all the properties but not the "options" field in QuestionSurvey domain. The error I'm getting is

```
TypeMismatchException: Provided id of the wrong type for class QuestionOptionSurvey.  

Expected class java.lang.Long got java.lang.String. So my question is how to get around   

this problem of binding params to a domain that has a field of type set of another domain 

class?
```

The params.options is a list of strings for example ['option1', 'option2', 'option2'].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to bind the `options` property/collection correctly your parameters should be posted with element names like: `options.optionText`. Otherwise it's going to expect you are posting ids and try and locate the `QuestionOptionSurvey` matching those ids.